# session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /var/lib/php5) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 81

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, memcached

I have i problem with myadminphp.
I try to go inside  admin area but when i use the url ,the page is white.
I have seen on the error.log and i have this error

> session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /var/lib/php5) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 81

I don't know what i can do!
Tx For all help

My session.inc.php

```
<?php
  /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
  /**
   * session handling
 *
 * @todo    add failover or warn if sessions are not configured properly
 * @todo    add an option to use mm-module for session handler
 * @see     http://www.php.net/session
 * @uses    session_name()
 * @uses    session_start()
 * @uses    ini_set()
 * @package phpMyAdmin
 */
if (! defined('PHPMYADMIN')) {
    exit;
}

// verify if PHP supports session, die if it does not

if (!@function_exists('session_name')) {
    PMA_warnMissingExtension('session', true);
} elseif (ini_get('session.auto_start') == true && session_name() != 'phpMyAdmin') {
    // Do not delete the existing session, it might be used by other
    // applications; instead just close it.
    session_write_close();
}

// disable starting of sessions before all settings are done
// does not work, besides how it is written in php manual
//ini_set('session.auto_start', 0);

// session cookie settings
session_set_cookie_params(0, $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->getCookiePath(),
    '', $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isHttps(), true);

// cookies are safer (use @ini_set() in case this function is disabled)
@ini_set('session.use_cookies', true);

// optionally set session_save_path
$path = $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('SessionSavePath');
if (!empty($path)) {
    session_save_path($path);
}

// but not all user allow cookies
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', false);
// do not force transparent session ids, see bug #3398788
//@ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', true);
@ini_set('url_rewriter.tags',
    'a=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry,fieldset=');
//ini_set('arg_separator.output', '&amp;');

// delete session/cookies when browser is closed
@ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);

// warn but dont work with bug
@ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', false);
@ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', true);

// use more secure session ids
@ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);

// some pages (e.g. stylesheet) may be cached on clients, but not in shared
// proxy servers
session_cache_limiter('private');

// start the session
// on some servers (for example, sourceforge.net), we get a permission error
// on the session data directory, so I add some "@"

// See bug #1538132. This would block normal behavior on a cluster
//ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');

$session_name = 'phpMyAdmin';
@session_name($session_name);

if (! isset($_COOKIE[$session_name])) {
    // on first start of session we check for errors
    // f.e. session dir cannot be accessed - session file not created
    $orig_error_count = $GLOBALS['error_handler']->countErrors();
    $r = session_start();
    if ($r !== true || $orig_error_count != $GLOBALS['error_handler']->countErrors()) {
        setcookie($session_name, '', 1);
        /*
         * Session initialization is done before selecting language, so we
         * can not use translations here.
         */
        PMA_fatalError('Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.');
    }
    unset($orig_error_count);
} else {
    session_start();
}

/**
 * Token which is used for authenticating access queries.
 * (we use "space PMA_token space" to prevent overwriting)
 */
if (!isset($_SESSION[' PMA_token '])) {
    $_SESSION[' PMA_token '] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}

/**
 * tries to secure session from hijacking and fixation
 * should be called before login and after successfull login
 * (only required if sensitive information stored in session)
 *
 * @uses    session_regenerate_id() to secure session from fixation
 */
function PMA_secureSession()
{
    // prevent session fixation and XSS
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION[' PMA_token '] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems like everyone involved on this question missed the fact that PHP was configured to use `memcache` as the session handler. File paths aren't relevant to using memcached for session storage. The `session.save_path` [is supposed to be a comma-separated list of hosts and ports](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php).

Answer (score 3):

usually it means you have a wrong path in `session.save_path` parameter in Apache config or php.ini

try to set

```
ini_set("session.save_path", "/path/to/tmp");
```

in the beginning of your file. If it helps, edit your php.ini file, otherwise try to find it somewhere, maybe in VirtualHost section

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give permission to access this directory.

On Windows, just open the directory and the system will ask you to change permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check code around:

```
// optionally set session_save_path
$path = $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('SessionSavePath');
if (!empty($path)) {
    session_save_path($path);
}
```

You may try commenting it out and test one more time (implementation of session_save_path() is not posted here and I suspect that the issue is there).

Comment: ok i have found the solution

     libraries/session.inc.php at line 79  // session.save_handler 
     ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');

Commenting out this line, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found the solution

```
 libraries/session.inc.php at line 79  // session.save_handler 
 ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
```

Commenting out this line, everything works fine.