# PHP session_start(); Error

Tags: php

for some reason my php script stops executing the php code after i state the session_start() action, 
This problem only occurs when i try to test it on a webserver (it works fine on xampp)

Here's a piece of the code: 
(Note in only works if i remove the session_start action.)

```
session_start(); 
//CODE STOPS HERE 
$date = date("Y-m-d"); 

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{ 
$username = ($_SESSION['username']); 

echo "<div id = 'registratie'> 
<form method='POST' action='register.php'> 


<h1>Registratie formulier</h>
```

this is the error i am getting:
Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /tmp) in /home/builder/domains/site-builder.nl/public_html/clients/nm/stagiares/stageproj‌​ectotman/member.php on line 27

```
Line 27: session_start();
```

Comment: Do you know what the error is? Can you turn on error reporting? (use `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`)

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: this is the error i am getting: Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /tmp) in /home/builder/domains/site-builder.nl/public_html/clients/nm/stagiares/stageprojectotman/member.php on line 27

Comment: Can we see line 27 of member.php?

Comment: Line 27 is the session_start(); action

Comment: possible duplicate of [session\_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /var/lib/php5) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 81](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387375/session-start-failed-to-initialize-storage-module-memcache-path-var-lib-p)

Comment: You're not closing PHP properly with `$username = ($_SESSION['username']); 

echo "<div id = 'registratie'>` plus, a missing closing brace `}`

Comment: the script is being propperly closed. That is just a small part of the code you are seeing, i only showed the crucial part that is giving the error.

Comment: Does site-builder.nl allow you to have your own sessions? If not then you have to set up your own session handler.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, not a PHP issue.  PHP is trying to store session data in memcache but there's a problem with your memcache config.  To confirm, try changing your php.ini file on that server to use the 'files' save handler per https://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Is that the _only_ error message, or are you also getting messages about "headers already sent"? Before or after this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP7.0.0 on xampp you may try the below:

Note: Just search the below in your 'php.ini' file located at 'c:\xampp\php\php.ini' to fix the issue: (chage the value to 1 from 0)

**use_only_cookies=1**

Source: https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=248070&sid=0b7559defe15317f41699d1ce9194e3f