# session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /tmp) when enable memcache in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2, memcached, php-7

Today we enabled memcache on centos and every thing is ok. PhpMyAdmin also run well with memcache but when i tried to login with my application that developed by yii2 i got this error:

```
session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /tmp)
```

After this i tried to enable memcache in yii2 config file same as documentation.

Here is my configuration in backend\config\main.php

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 11211,
                'weight' => 60,
            ],
        ],
        'useMemcached' => true,

    ],
```

But after everything, problem not solved and i tired from searching web.

In no forum and in no site no body don't talk why i face to this problem.

Thanks for your help.
This is so important because my admin page is crashed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session\_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: /var/lib/php5) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 81](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387375/session-start-failed-to-initialize-storage-module-memcache-path-var-lib-p)

Comment: I dont think. Framework handle the session not me and this problem happen just when memcache enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.

Just need edit your session configuration in yii application configuration from default to cache type